# Unable to execute Active Directory Commands

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, windows-server-2012-r2, winrm

I am unable to use Active Directory commands like `Get-ADDomain`, `Get-ADUser`, etc in a PowerShell script using Ansible. Basic commands like `ls`, `New-Item` work fine.

### Environment

```
ad-dns.test.com    - Windows 2012 AD and DNS Server
box88.test.com     - CentOS 7.2 (Not joined to domain) : Ansible, Kerberos, Python 
box62.test.com     - Windows 2012 R2 Standard (Joined to domain)
vkumar@TEST.COM    - Domain User for the Kerberos Ticket
```

### Configuration

I have enabled WinRM on Windows Server 2012 through [ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1) PowerShell script.

### PowerShell Script

This is the basic script which I am trying to execute through Ansible.

```
ls
New-Item -Path C:\testfile.txt -ItemType file
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-Module
Get-ADDomain
```

### Problem

When I execute the above script, `ActiveDirectory` module appears to be loaded properly but all Active Directory commands fails with below error:

> Get-ADDomain : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.

Interestingly, the same script executes without any errors directly on PowerShell.

Here is the detailed output of Ansible.

```
root@box88:~# ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/win_test.yml

PLAY [windows] *****************************************************************

TASK [wintest : include] *******************************************************
included: /etc/ansible/roles/wintest/tasks/win_test.yml for box62.test.com

TASK [wintest : script] ********************************************************
changed: [box62.test.com]

TASK [wintest : debug] *********************************************************
ok: [box62.test.com] => {
    "res.stdout_lines + [ res.stderr ]": [
        "",
        "",
        "    Directory: C:\\Users\\vkumar",
        "",
        "",
        "Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              ",
        "----                -------------     ------ ----                              ",
        "d-r--         6/28/2016   9:10 AM            Contacts                          ",
        "d-r--         7/19/2016   9:30 PM            Desktop                           ",
        "d-r--         6/28/2016   9:10 AM            Documents                         ",
        "d-r--         6/28/2016   9:10 AM            Downloads                         ",
        "d-r--         6/28/2016   9:10 AM            Favorites                         ",
        "d-r--         6/28/2016   9:10 AM            Links                             ",
        "d-r--         6/28/2016   9:10 AM            Music                             ",
        "d-r--         6/28/2016   9:10 AM            Pictures                          ",
        "",
        "",
        "    Directory: C:\\",
        "",
        "",
        "Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              ",
        "----                -------------     ------ ----                              ",
        "-a---         7/19/2016  10:01 PM          0 testfile.txt                      ",
        "",
        "Name              : ActiveDirectory",
        "Path              : C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\ActiveDi",
        "                    rectory\\ActiveDirectory.psd1",
        "Description       : ",
        "Guid              : 43c15630-959c-49e4-a977-758c5cc93408",
        "Version           : 1.0.0.0",
        "ModuleBase        : C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\ActiveDi",
        "                    rectory",
        "ModuleType        : Manifest",
        "PrivateData       : ",
        "AccessMode        : ReadWrite",
        "ExportedAliases   : {}",
        "ExportedCmdlets   : {[Add-ADCentralAccessPolicyMember, ",
        "                    Add-ADCentralAccessPolicyMember], ",
        "                    [Add-ADComputerServiceAccount, ",
        "                    Add-ADComputerServiceAccount], ",
        "                    [Add-ADDomainControllerPasswordReplicationPolicy, ",
        "                    Add-ADDomainControllerPasswordReplicationPolicy], ",
        "                    [Add-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicySubject, ",
        "                    Add-ADFineGrainedPasswordPolicySubject]...}",
        "ExportedFunctions : {}",
        "ExportedVariables : {}",
        "NestedModules     : {Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management}",
        "",
        "",
        "Name              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Management",
        "Path              : C:\\windows\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\Modules\\Microsof",
        "                    t.PowerShell.Management\\Microsoft.PowerShell.Management.psd",
        "                    1",
        "Description       : ",
        "Guid              : eefcb906-b326-4e99-9f54-8b4bb6ef3c6d",
        "Version           : 3.1.0.0",
        "ModuleBase        : C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0",
        "ModuleType        : Manifest",
        "PrivateData       : ",
        "AccessMode        : ReadWrite",
        "ExportedAliases   : {}",
        "ExportedCmdlets   : {[Add-Computer, Add-Computer], [Add-Content, Add-Content], ",
        "                    [Checkpoint-Computer, Checkpoint-Computer], ",
        "                    [Clear-Content, Clear-Content]...}",
        "ExportedFunctions : {}",
        "ExportedVariables : {}",
        "NestedModules     : {Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll}",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "Get-ADDomain : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server \r\ndoes not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory \r\nWeb Services running.\r\nAt C:\\Users\\vkumar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1468990893.98-136722234533486\r\n\\test.ps1:5 char:1\r\n+ Get-ADDomain\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (TEST:ADDomain) [Get-ADDoma \r\nin], ADServerDownException\r\n+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirector \r\ny.Management.Commands.GetADDomain\r\n"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
box62.test.com             : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

root@box88:~#
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled onto an identical issue last week while configuring a PowerShell worker node for running AD scripts. After some digging around I found the [Ansible WinRM guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html) and reviewed the [limitations section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html#limitations). Shortly afterwards, I found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1007403/ansible-to-properly-use-powershell-remote-sessions) on ServerFault, which raised my suspicion that it is a Kerberos double hop authentication issue - particularly from comments and answers from user Semicolon.

So, I followed this suggestion in the Ansible documentation (the same one echoed by Semicolon):

> - Set `ansible_winrm_transport` to `credssp` or `kerberos` (with `ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation=true`) to bypass the double hop issue and access network resources

In my scenario, `ansible_winrm_transport` was already set to `kerberos` in my group variables file. My solution was to add this line:

`ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: true`

to my group variables file. After that addition, I ran my playbook which runs a script called TestAD.ps1, which attempts to run `Get-ADDomain`. This was the resulting Ansible output:

```
ok: [psworker.domain.com] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "powershell.exe C:/scripts/TestAD.ps1", 
        "delta": "0:00:01.101562", 
        "end": "2020-07-31 09:08:44.785758", 
        "failed": false, 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2020-07-31 09:08:43.684196", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "Unrestricted", 
            "", 
            "", 
            "AllowedDNSSuffixes                 : {}", 
            "ChildDomains                       : {}", 
            "ComputersContainer                 : OU=mydomain Servers,DC=mydomain,DC=com", 
            "DeletedObjectsContainer            : CN=Deleted Objects,DC=mydomain,DC=com", 
            "DistinguishedName                  : DC=mydomain,DC=com", 
            "DNSRoot                            : mydomain.com", 
            "DomainControllersContainer         : OU=Domain Controllers,DC=mydomain,DC=com", 
            "DomainMode                         : Windows2012R2Domain", 
            "DomainSID                          : S-1-5-21-644830395-273481423-308473177", 
            "ForeignSecurityPrincipalsContainer : CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=mydomain,DC=com", 
            "Forest                             : mydomain.com", 
            "InfrastructureMaster               : devdc00.mydomain.com", 
            "LastLogonReplicationInterval       : ", 
            "LinkedGroupPolicyObjects           : {cn={BD2441AA-23B7-4D11-B499-73642A1734A8},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=mydomain,DC=", 
            "                                     com, cn={E73254A1-C013-4D45-8BB3-FEE2E1300B11},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=mydomain", 
            "                                     ,DC=com, cn={CF7575AC-E140-4869-B8C7-904C753D8E28},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=mydoma", 
            "                                     in,DC=com, cn={C63CB9EB-262E-4AD7-BC0B-70B3EF2F7B48},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=my", 
            "                                     domain,DC=com...}", 
            "LostAndFoundContainer              : CN=LostAndFound,DC=mydomain,DC=com", 
            "ManagedBy                          : ", 
            "Name                               : mydomain", 
            "NetBIOSName                        : mydomain", 
            "ObjectClass                        : domainDNS", 
            "ObjectGUID                         : 6f59e1a2-8857-46f2-90fd-51710bde58d6", 
            "ParentDomain                       : ", 
            "PDCEmulator                        : devdc00.mydomain.com", 
            "PublicKeyRequiredPasswordRolling   : ", 
            "QuotasContainer                    : CN=NTDS Quotas,DC=mydomain,DC=com", 
            "ReadOnlyReplicaDirectoryServers    : {}", 
            "ReplicaDirectoryServers            : {dc01.mydomain.com, devdc00.mydomain.com}", 
            "RIDMaster                          : dc00.mydomain.com", 
            "SubordinateReferences              : {DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mydomain,DC=com, DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mydomain,DC=com, ", 
            "                                     CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=com}", 
            "SystemsContainer                   : CN=System,DC=mydomain,DC=com", 
            "UsersContainer                     : CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com", 
            "", 
            "", 
            ""
        ]
    }
}
```

Here are the settings in my group_vars file (can be set in the playbook directly):

```
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: true
ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos
```

I use the exact same PowerShell script to configure WinRM for Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like PowerShell can not discover a Domain Controller while in the Ansible environment?
Can you instead run:

```
Get-ADDomain -Server MyDomainController
```